# Magento2 - Listen for order new comments

Tags: magento2, event-observer, plugin, dependency-injection

I am trying to create some kind of observer that will listen for new order comments and execute the function every time a comment is added.

I tried three ways that did not work for me:

> - Observer listening for order changes;
> - Plugin on order changes;
> - Dependency injection on add comment original class running the commands within the original function.

**Anyone can give me an idea of what can really work ?** If you could paste basic code to get me direct to the point would really help me.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @anas-mansuri thank you for the edition, do you have a reply for this question too ?

Comment: Do you want to catch `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/AddComment.php`?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh that would be great. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I confirm that I worked on di for this Controller and it worked fine. Thank you very much for your help.